# Which are the most popular cartoons on academia?

Tags: academic-life

I find self-criticism and irony are strong means to communicate genuinely and involve people who are not necessarily expert in a field.

As cartoons offer a quick yet poignant way to describe how academia works, I am wondering which cartoons on academia are the most popular. I am interested in particular on cartoons which may highlight the true spirit of academic life and academic hierarchy.

A simple Google search for "cartoon academia" yields 580,000 hits, with the first image posted being a [New Yorker cartoon by David Sipress](http://www.condenaststore.com/-sp/Daddy-works-in-a-magical-faraway-land-called-Academia-New-Yorker-Cartoon-Prints_i8546667_.htm). Is such ranking correct?

Comment: I'm not a regular in Academia, so take this with a grain of salt, but this kind of question is broadly considered off-topic on SE (a list question, aka "Primarily Opinion-Based").

Comment: Yes, you need to be more specific, because taste varies. That being said, xkcd and PhDComics are good starting points.

Comment: @DanBron I see your point. However, it could be an interesting set of Q/A. Indeed, I was inspired by this CV post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-is-your-favorite-data-analysis-cartoon

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I have somewhat expanded the post.

Comment: @DanBron I think that in this case the list is so limited that it could be considered on-topic.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: I beg to disagree. I alone know at least a dozen possible answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

[xykademiqz](https://xykademiqz.com/category/cartoons/)

Not to be confused with

[xkcd](https://xkcd.com/)

Both very good. This is one of my favourites from xykademiqz:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As a graduate student, I personally enjoy [PHD Comics](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1892). They humorously (and often painfully) give a realistic picture of academic life from a grad student/postdoc's perspective.

Exhibit A:

[image: example PHD comic]
<sub>(source: [phdcomics.com](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd082416s.gif))</sub>

They're often used here in similar context to "[obligatory xkcd](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42627/what-questions-to-prepare-for-phd-defense/42629#comment94648_42627)" references. Relatedly, [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/) is another comic I enjoy, slightly less relevant to academia, but often containing [references](https://xkcd.com/1781/) to academic situations.